# Unwrapping the value of an Identity monad

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I have been playing a little bit with scalaz and I am stuck on a seemingly trivial issue. I was playing around with the Reader and Kliesli monads and found myself with something like this:

```
val gr = Reader { (_: Int) + 1 }
val a = gr(1)
```

That dutifully responds:

```
a: scalaz.Id.Id[Int] = 2
```

What I am trying to do now is to unwrap the Int from the Identity monad, for that I should be using the ?? operator, with this signature:

```
final def ??(d: => A)(implicit ev: Null <:< A): A
```

The first parameter I should pass is a default value, a call by name Int (as pointed by  Brian McCutchon) :

```
scala> a??(1)
<console>:19: error: Cannot prove that Null <:<   scalaz.Id.Id[Int].
   a??(1)
    ^
```

I would like to understand what I am missing here before I keep moving.
Thanks
EDITED to fix my confusion about call-by-name with no parameters function. Shame.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem, but .. do you actually need to unwrap it?  `val a: Int = 2:scalaz.Id.Id[Int]` . You can use wrapped value the same way as unwrapped.

Comment: `=> A` is not a function that takes no parameters; that would be `() => A`. It's actually a call-by-name parameter. That explains the first error.

Comment: @Brian, yes you are of course right

Comment: @Bodgan, no I actually do not need to do that. But I find very annoying that I can not do it, I suspect i am missing something, that my understanding is more limited than I though

Answer (score 0):

`a` is already an `Int`; see [the definition](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.26/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Id.scala#L13).

edit: There are no methods to unwrap because there is nothing to unwrap; the type the REPL prints for `a` is just another way of saying `Int`.